# Change UTF-8 character to Latin1 Java

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In my project I read Strings from my database, where I can not do any change because of permissions. I take a string in any codification, and I change it to UTF-8 without any problem for instance:

```
String countryName= "ESPAÃƒâ€˜A";   //get from de DataBase in unkwon encode
String utf8 = new String(myString.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(utf8); //prints -> ESPAÃ‘A and it should be ESPAÑA
```

I need to change it, with all the strings that are parse to UTF-8, and covert it to Latin1

I have found many methods in the page but anything it is doing correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure You understand subject, or I understand You. Java String has only one legal form (unicode under the mask), Bytes can hold 8 bit characters in codepage what is wanted.

Comment: I don't think we can help you without details for your DB (i.e. the vendor) and the way that you have configured it, and are connecting to it.  What you are doing should not be necessary ... if the DB / connection are configured appropriately.

Comment: The problem is not the DB because I am trying it too in a simple project where I give the String and it does not work. I only change a String in UTF-8, with characters like ESPAÃ‘A, to Latin1 like ESPAÑA. It could be too like a replace from UTF-8 characters to the sepecific Latin1 character.

Comment: Agreed with @StephenC. I'd add : if you have a java String object, and this string shows a bad charset interpretation has been done, then the game is already over. There is (in the general case) no amount of converting that can revert this damage (information has been lost). So, like Stephen said, we should see what gave the damaged String in the first place, and prevent that. Sidenote : there is no way to change a char's encoding because chars are an encoding-free concept in Java (at the language level at least). Char to byte *conversion* (and vice versa) is where encodings come into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the encoding of the original bytes, you can't transcode them to a known form. I wrote a paper for the Unicode consortium on this problem. see [Mapping Text in Unspecified Character Sets to Unicode as a Canonical Representation in a Hostile Environment](http://unicode.org/iuc/iuc26/abstracts.html#a303)

This code
`new String(myString.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")`
means, I have the bytes in UTF-8, convert them into a Java String.

UTF-8 can support the full range of Unicode characters (about 2^21 at the moment). Latin 1 can only support 2^8 characters.

So, transcoding from UTF-8 to Latin-1 is dangerous, as some characters will be lost, and you will need lost character exception handling.

Transcoding from Latin-1 to UTF-8 is fine, as all characters in Latin-1 are supported in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. But in fact it is only the main characters as the Alphabet that I want to convert, like in this table: http://www.merinomartinez.com/2012/06/tabla-de-conversion-de-simbolos-utf-8-a-iso-8859-1-ansi/ . I think that it would be enough for my Strings that I want to convert.

Comment: I would still strongly suggest that you try to keep all your strings in a Unicode form rather than trying to downgrade them.
You seem pretty decided that you want them in Latin-1, but that means your code will break if, at any time in the future, even one character outside that set is used.

The reason that Java was designed to use Unicode natively is to try to ensure that these type breakages don't occur.

This is why all the standards from the World Wide Web Consortium have, for a very long time defaulted to a unicode encoding such as UTF-8.

Answer (score -2):

`String#getBytes()` returns the text as bytes using the system encoding. What you need is a byte array containing the value of each character without any conversion taking place to keep the UTF8 encoding. You can do that by calling

```
myString.getBytes("8859_1");
```

So your line in the code should be changed to

```
String utf8 = new String(myString.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF8");
```

But this is just a workaround. What you should do before is check the access to the database, since the data should come out this way when selecting data from it. As a first test, use a regular DB-client and see if the text shows up correctly in it. If that's the case, the table contains the data correctly and there is something wrong with your data retrieval from the DB. This might be wrong charset settings in the connection-string or you don't use `resultset#getString()` to get the data as text but maybe you get it as byte-array and create the String in a wrong way.

Try to find the source of this and fix that. Then you don't need hacks like the above to get correct data.

Comment: The main thing that I want to do is change a UTF-8 String to Latin1. From ESPAÃ‘A to ESPAÑA. But it has to be for all UTF-8 characters to Latin1 characters.

Comment: Even though a lot of people always keep answering this, `new String(foo.getBytes(encoding1), encoding2)` has never worked, doesn't work nor will it ever work. It will however corrupt the contents of the String in most cases. When it doesn't corrupt the String, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry but your statement isn't true if UTF-8 data is read in as ISO-8859-1 which seems to be the case here. In that case my solution perfectly works and I've used it a couple of times already to solve problems like this in production environments. So if you were the reason for the downvote, please consider reversing that.

Comment: I won't. The correct course of action is to read the data in properly. Not try to fix it when it's already corrupted. If you've used this in production environments, it really isn't something you want to boast about.

Comment: @Kayaman It seems you haven't read the answer till the end where I explicitly said that fixing the source of the problem is better than trying workarounds like the one I specified.

Comment: Remove your "workaround" and I'll remove my downvote. I can't allow you to propagate this sort of false information, when people get easily confused about encoding. That's not a workaround, that's a glaring bug in code.

Comment: After this comment this is EOD for me. The workaround I specified is valid for certain situations and I described where. I don't brag for votes and I stand by what I've said, so I won't change my answer just for that. I think readers of my answer and the following discussion in form of these comments will help to see the boundaries of the solution and avoid "confusion".

Comment: Unfortunately I can tell you from experience that the readers won't see that. I have been answering these kinds of questions for a while, and it's really hard for people to get their head around encodings, even with plenty of examples. Suggesting `new String(foo.getBytes(encoding1), encoding2)` is dangerous, because the readers don't understand what that really means and why it is wrong.